# Can't find my file after writeToFile

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I was trying to create a CSV file using xcode but I can't seem to find the file anywhere after creation.

One solution I found was going into products folder itself but it isn't there.

Another solution that didn't work: Window-> Devices-> look at the installed apps of the devices but the container is empty.

Here is my code:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *root = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.csv"];

    // Append file here 
    temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", (float)*samples];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:root]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: root contents:nil attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Route created");
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@", root);
    BOOL success = [temp writeToFile:root atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"fail to write to csv file");
    }
```

It always is successful, but yet I can't find the file, also the file also seem to exists as it does not enter the if(fileExistsAtPath) after the first time.
The root directory is : /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDA4F37D-8D61-43F9-809C-31B09852B77F/Documents/test.csv

Edit: to make it clearer, I'm trying to retrieve it via xcode. Through finder so that I can get the csv file. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your use of `fileExistsAtPath` and `createFileAtPath` are pointless. Remove that code.

Comment: Did you try to write code that loads the csv file from the Documents folder or try calling `fileExistsAtPath` after writing it?

Comment: @rmaddy hmm I did something like    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:root]) {
        NSLog(@"File exist");
    }
After writing it and it works okay.

Comment: Then the file exists. What's the issue?

Comment: @rmaddy I cant find the file anywhere. I need to use the csv file.

Comment: Huh? You just said it exists. Why can't you find it? It's in `root`. Are you trying to get the file off of the device?

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah. I'm trying to get it off the device through xcode.

Comment: 1) Run the app in the Simulator. 2) Download the app's container through the Devices window. Then find the Documents folder inside the downloaded container. 3) Provide a feature in your app that lets you email the file. 4) Enable file sharing in your app so you can access the file through iTunes.